# Meteor: autoform template issue upgrading project from 0.9.3.1 to 1.2.0.2

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting the error below when I try to navigate to the route.  This was working fine on the 0.9.3.1 version of Meteor but after recently upgrading and redeveloping my project to the latest version of Meteor I'm running in to a few issues.

This is the template that appears to be causing the issue:

```
<template name="addCompetition">
  {{#autoForm collection="Competitions" id="addCompetition" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add a Competition</legend>

       {{> afQuickField name='correctEntry'}}
       {{> afQuickField name='prizeFund'}}     

       {{> cfsFileField name="imageId" collection="competitionimages"}}

    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

Error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 Error: No such template: cfsFileField
    at Blaze.View.lookup (lookup.js:184)
    at null.<anonymous> (spacebars-runtime.js:32)
    at view.js:199
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:457)
    at view.js:197
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at viewAutorun (view.js:196)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:323)
    at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js:211)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js:562)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

This is the output of `meteor list`:

```
accounts-password                  1.1.3  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui                        1.1.6  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
alanning:roles                     1.2.13+ Authorization package for Meteor
aldeed:autoform                    5.5.1  Easily create forms with automatic insert and update, and automatic reactive...
aldeed:collection2                 2.5.0  Automatic validation of insert and update operations on the client and server.
aldeed:simple-schema               1.3.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 and a...
blaze-html-templates               1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
cfs:autoform                       2.2.1  Upload files as part of autoform submission
cfs:filesystem                     0.1.2  Filesystem storage adapter for CollectionFS
cfs:gridfs                         0.0.33  GridFS storage adapter for CollectionFS
cfs:standard-packages              0.5.9  Filesystem for Meteor, collectionFS
ecmascript                         0.1.5  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
ejson                              1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library
es5-shim                           4.1.13  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
insecure                           1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client
iron:router                        1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jquery                             1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
matb33:collection-hooks            0.8.0  Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for insert/update/remove/fi...
meteor-base                        1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteorhacks:npm                    1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
mobile-experience                  1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                              1.1.2  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3  0.2.7  A roles based account management system using bootstrap 3
mrt:jquery-jcrop                   0.0.3  jQuery Jcrop repackaged for Meteor
mrt:loading                        0.0.1  Loading overlay + spinner
npm-container                      1.2.0+ Contains all your npm dependencies
random                             1.0.4  Random number generator and utilities
session                            1.1.1  Session variable
spacebars                          1.0.7  Handlebars-like template language for Meteor
standard-minifiers                 1.0.1  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                            1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap                     3.3.5  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it's a big jump :)

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-cfs-autoform

`cfsFileField` is depreacted and now it should be something like:

```
{{> afQuickField name="imageId" type="cfs-file" collection="competitionimages"}}
```

Comment: Sure is a big jump, a lot to catch up on!  Your suggestion worked, thank you very much :)